# SPL/TMG -LAPL-A to PPL

Tags: pilot-certification, ppl, easa, lapl, tmg

If you follow the educational path from Sailplane Pilot License / Touring motorglider (SPL/TMG) to Light Aircraft Pilot Licence (LAPL-A/SEP).

What is the requirement to progress from LAPL-A to a Private Pilot License (PPL)?

Can you fly TMG to collect the hours on the way to PPL?  Navigation flight?  Solo flight?

Can you use an SPL/TMG flight instructor in that process?